# error C1084: Cannot read type library file

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-c++, typelib

I have a windows application including some console and c++ projects.
While building application i am getting below mentioned error:-

**error C1084: Cannot read type library file...
   Biodentify.Gina.Services.tlb:
   Error loading type library/dll**

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you working on any Biometric or any hardware Device?

Comment: have you registered that DLL with regasm in the machine which is
going to consume this DLL?

Comment: Could you tell me the process?

Comment: You can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx). You just need to call this application with specific parameter.

Comment: if i am using "regasm myTest.dll /tlb:myTest.tlb" this command then getting error
Error RA0000 unable to locate input assembly 'myTest.dll' or its dependencies

Comment: The error reason might be your dll file path. check the dll file path is correct. if there is a space in the dll path then pass that path enclosed by double quotation. If it doesn't solve your issue then you need to check all dependent dll file is exists or not. You can check dependencies by using [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com)

Comment: Checkout this [link](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/4F811A9B23F1D46E862566F700615B7A) also.

Comment: Thank u.
Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Is the type library at the right place?
- Are your app and the type library both 32bit or 64bit?
- Are there any includes in your type library?

If your type library includes another type library, keep in mind that the search path
is the app search path.

One more tricky thing: If a type library has an include, and this included type library is registered, it will be found first.