# Calling Sap2000 by C++

Tags: c++

I want to call sap2000 by C++, and I followed the **CSI_OAPI_DOCUMENTATION** as following:

> Create a Visual C++ Win32 project using the template “Win32 Console
> Application”.
>
> In Win32 Application Wizard, add common header files for ATL under
> Application Settings tab.
>
> Create a folder named “tlb” under the project folder and copy
> “Sap2000.tlb” from the installation folder to the “tlb” folder.
>
> Create a folder named “C:\API” if it does not exist.
>
> Open the "stdafx.h" file generated by the wizard by double clicking on
> it and add the following line to the end of the document:
>
> ```
>   #include <atlsafe.h>
> ```
>
> Open the .cpp file generated by the wizard by double clicking on it
> and paste in the following code:
>
> ```
>   #include "stdafx.h"
>
>   #include <sstream>
>   #include <iomanip>
>   #include <math.h>
>
>   #import "..\tlb\Sap2000.tlb" high_property_prefixes("Get_","Put_","PutRef_") no_smart_pointers no_namespace raw_native_types rename("min", "sap2000v12_min") rename("SetProp", "sap2000v12_SetProp") rename("GetProp", "sap2000v12_GetProp") rename("Yield", "sap2000v12_Yield")
> ```

However,it doesn't work. There is something wrong with  `#import "..\tlb\Sap2000.tlb"` I can't solve it.

error:

```
fatal error C1084: Cannot read type library file: 'C:\Users\yanyan\Desktop\test\test\test\tlb\SAP2000.TLB': Error loading type library/DLL.
```

Comment: _How_ does it not work? What's the error message? The code starting with `no_namespace` is a part of the code to paste?

Comment: I edited the question, the error is showed in the end. If you can tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Great, we can search for the error code now. What about checking these tips? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22370091/711006 or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/860460af-401c-46df-a24f-62e824d9744a/cannot-read-type-library-error-c1084

Comment: I have used full path of SAP2000.tlb and I don't know if it need other dll files.Since the documentation doesn't require import ohter dll, it may not need other dll files. It seems that "SAP2000.tlb" doesn't be registered. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this process before and I have used the API of the SAP2000.
You have to add the .tlb file into the resources of your solution to be able to access its classes, etc.
you also can place the .tlb file wherever you want, I recommend placing it right beside your .cpp code.